# How do I replace the GLUT title bar icon when using pyopengl?

Tags: python, opengl, freeglut

I am trying to learn OpenGL, and I'm using PyOpenGL and GLUT.
What really bugs me, is that I can't figure out how to change the
title bar icon. Has anyone had any success in changing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.

Remember: GLUT is primarily for test applications and demos. If your application is complex and platform-specific enough to need to change its icon, then you probably need to move beyond GLUT.